# Function not executing for every item (except last) in list while iterating through them

Tags: python, kivy

I have my **update_entities** function that is constantly updating my "entities' " states. The *upward* and *downward* functions activate the prototype movement for the entities.

The reason the function is in a for loop is because in each "round" in my game there are three *entities* / *enemies*, so the loop iterates through each of the entities and takes control of their states (positions and whether they shot their weapons).

The problem I'm running into is the shooting function, the function itself works just fine but only for the 3rd of the three entities. It's quite weird behavior and definitely unexpected, I don't understand why that's been happening because when iterating through each of the entities, each of them gets an opportunity to move in an oscillating behavior, but, again, the 3rd one is the only one that shoots.

Here is the code that could relate to the problem.

```
    entity_bullet = None
    ebullet_coordinates = [(0, 0), (0, 0)]
    entity_bullets = []

    def get_ebullet_coordinates(self):
        for child in self.entity_bullets:
            x1, y1 = child.pos
            self.ebullet_coordinates[0] = (x1, y1)

            x2, y2 = child.pos[0] + child.width, child.pos[1] + child.height
            self.ebullet_coordinates[1] = (x2, y2)

    def entity_shoot(self):
        for child in self.entities:
            self.get_entity_coordinates()

            x = self.entity_coordinates[0][0]
            y = self.entity_coordinates[0][1] - 20

            if child.source == "images/evil_drone.png":
                self.entity_bullet = Image(source="images/evil_drone_bullet2.png",
                                           pos=(x, y))

            elif child.source == "images/angry_cloud.png":
                self.entity_bullet = Image(source="images/lightning_bullet2.png",
                                           pos=(x, y))

            elif child.source == "images/skullairballoon.png":
                self.entity_bullet = Image(source="images/bomb.png",
                                           pos=(x, y))

            self.add_widget(self.entity_bullet)
            self.entity_bullets.append(self.entity_bullet)  # Add to list for them to move

    def update_entity_bullets(self):
        self.get_drone_coordinates()
        self.get_entity_coordinates()

        drone_xmin, drone_ymin = self.drone_coordinates[0][0], self.drone_coordinates[0][1]
        drone_xmax, drone_ymax = self.drone_coordinates[1][0], self.drone_coordinates[1][1]

        bullet_xmin, bullet_ymin = self.entity_coordinates[0][0], self.entity_coordinates[0][1] - 20
        bullet_xmax, bullet_ymax = self.entity_coordinates[1][0], self.entity_coordinates[1][1]

        xdistance = bullet_xmax - drone_xmin
        ydistance = bullet_ymin - drone_ymax

        final_xdistance = (xdistance / 60) + 1
        final_ydistance = (ydistance / 60) + 1

        for self.entity_bullet in self.entity_bullets:
            for child in self.entity_bullets:
                if child.pos[1] <= 0:
                    self.remove_widget(child)

                elif child.pos[1] >= self.height - 10:
                    self.remove_widget(child)

                if child.pos[0] <= -10:
                    self.remove_widget(child)

                elif child.pos[0] >= self.width - 10:
                    self.remove_widget(child)

            self.entity_bullet.pos[0] -= final_xdistance
            self.entity_bullet.pos[1] -= final_ydistance

        pass

     def check_ebullet_collision(self, dt):
        if self.game_ongoing:
            self.get_drone_coordinates()
            self.get_ebullet_coordinates()

            drone_xmin, drone_ymin = self.drone_coordinates[0][0], self.drone_coordinates[0][1]
            drone_xmax, drone_ymax = self.drone_coordinates[1][0], self.drone_coordinates[1][1]

            bullet_xmin, bullet_ymin = self.ebullet_coordinates[0][0], self.ebullet_coordinates[0][1]
            bullet_xmax, bullet_ymax = self.ebullet_coordinates[1][0], self.ebullet_coordinates[1][1]

           
            if ((drone_xmax - 40) >= bullet_xmin >= (drone_xmin - 50)) and ((drone_ymax - 65) >= bullet_ymin >= (drone_ymin - 50)):
                print("hit")
                for self.entity_bullet in self.entity_bullets:
                    self.remove_widget(self.entity_bullet)
                    for ebullet in self.entity_bullets:
                        self.entity_bullets.remove(ebullet)
                        self.remove_widget(ebullet)


    def update_entities(self):
        for child in self.entities:
            z = random.randint(1, 3000)
            a = random.randint(1, 215)

            def upward():
                child.pos[1] += .1

            def downward():
                child.pos[1] -= .1

            if z >= 2800 or z % 2 == 0:
                for i in range(random.randint(1, 20)):
                    upward()

            else:
                for i in range(random.randint(1, 22)):
                    downward()

            if a == 205:
                self.entity_shoot()
```

Comment: It looks to me like the probability of a child shooting is on the order of magnitude of 1/215 0r 0.47%  is this what you wanted?   This estimate is based on the fact you are generating a randint in range 1, 215 and testing if a == 205.  Given these odds, it is no wonder only 1 child shoots

Comment: Actually, the process happens 600x faster because the entity_update function is connected to the main update function which I imported from update.py. The update function is run on a Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 600). In fact the one entity shooting is not a rare occurrence at all.

Comment: While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: The for loop in `entity_shoot()` doesn't save its results, so the only result you get is the last one.

Comment: In `entity_shoot()`, the line that actually appends a new bullet to the list is *outside the loop* - only the final child is able to create a bullet, because everything the previous children did was overwritten.

Comment: Putting that line inside the loop did seem to help, now each of the children shoots their bullet, but only at the last child's coordinates, though I believe that could be dealt with by a few alterations to how the coordinates are appended in their respective lists.